# Representations of the centre of the Group ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, group-rings

Given a finite group $G$, let $\rho:G \to GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ be an irreducible representation of $G$.

Now consider the group ring $\mathbb{C}G$. There is a very natural way of extending $\rho$ to $\rho^{*}$ a representation of $\mathbb{C}G$:

Let $\sum_{g\in G}\lambda_{g}g\in \mathbb{C}G$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, then:

$$\rho^{*}(\sum_{g\in G}\lambda_{g}g)=\sum_{g\in G}\lambda_{g}\rho*(g)$$

Now, denote $Z(\mathbb{C}G)=\{z\in\mathbb{C}G : zr=rz \hspace{0.5cm}\forall r \in \mathbb{C}G\}$.

I am wondering whether there is a method to obtain an *irreducible* representation of $Z(\mathbb{C}G)$ given an irreducible representation of the group ring.

I have noticed that since $Z(\mathbb{C}G)$ is a commutative ring, it follows that all its irreducible representations must be 1-dimensional, but I do not know how they relate (if they do) to the representations of the $\mathbb{C}G$.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Look up *central characters*

Answer (score 2):

Since the representation $\rho$ is irreducible and the field $\mathbf{C}$ is algebraically closed, any $G$-module endomorphism of $\rho$ must be a multiplication by a scalar. This in particular applies to each central element $z \in Z(\mathbf{C}G)$ of the group algebra. It follows that there is a homomorphism $\alpha_\rho:Z(\mathbf{C}G) \to \mathbf{C}$ of $\mathbf{C}$-algebras sending $z$ to the scalar by which it acts on the vector space underlying the representation $\rho$. This homomorphism $\alpha_\rho$ is called the *central character* associated with $\rho$. In particular, as a representation of $Z(\mathbf{C}G)$, the space $\mathbf{C}^n$ is the direct sum of $n$ copies of the same $1$-dimensional irreducible representation given by $\alpha_\rho$.

You can compute the values of $\alpha_\rho$ in terms of the character
$$\chi_\rho(g)=\mathrm{tr}(\rho(g))$$ of $\rho$ as follows: if
$$z=\sum_{g \in G} c_g g$$ then the trace of $\rho(z)$ is the dimension $n$ of $\rho$ times the scalar value $\alpha_\rho(z)$ by which $z$ acts. Thus
$$\alpha_\rho(z)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{g\in G}  c_g \chi_\rho(g).$$

Comment: that is exactly the result I was hoping for. Thank you!

Comment: @FacundoCanale I'm glad it was helpful! I suppose you should accept it as an answer, then?

Comment: Yes sorry, I am still quite new on this platform :/. Will do right away, thank you :).

Comment: @FacundoCanale No worries!